# Запутанная выборка из нескольких таблиц MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Задача на мой взгляд нетривиальная.
Есть три таблицы:

1. `user` (в ней хранится информация о строителях);
2. `sfera` (в ней хранится информация о том, в каких категориях строители оказывают свои услуги);
3. `favorites` (в ней хранится информация о строителях, которых пользователи добавили к себе в избранные, с разбивкой по категориям; то есть один и тот же строитель может оказывать услуги в трех категориях, но при этом быть добавленным в избранные только в одной категории).

Когда мы загружаем каталог строителей в определенной категории, например, "Внутренние работы", мы отбираем их следующим образом:

```
SELECT sfera.*, 
    user.photo as photo, 
    user.city as city, 
    sfera.additional 
FROM sfera, user 
WHERE sfera.is_confirmed = '1' 
    AND sfera.sfera_value = 'Внутренние работы' 
    AND sfera.city_value = 'Москва'
    AND user.user_id = sfera.user_id 
ORDER BY rating DESC
```

**Вопрос**:
Как добавить к результатам запроса информацию о том, есть ли у строителя отметка о добавлении в избранные в ЭТОЙ категории (Внутренние работы)?

Структура таблицы `favorites`:

```
id          // id записи   
person_id   // id пользователя, добавившего строителя в избранные   
user_id     // id строителя, добавленного в избранные   
sferaValue  // идентификатор конкретной категории, в которой строитель добавлен в избранные 
is_favorite // по умолчанию 1
```

Comment: Замените `,` в from на полноценный join и добавьте left join подзапроса, который получает из третьей таблицы id-пользователя, id-категории с group by по этим полям, т.е. что бы у него на выходе было не более одной записи по пользователю-категории

Comment: я не очень понимаю, как работают join запросы, не могли бы вы отразить изменения на примере вышеуказанного запроса? Спасибо.

Comment: join от `,` ничем не отличается, только условие объединения из where переносится в `on` этого join

Comment: @Mike а от этого план запроса не изменяется?

Comment: обычно нет. запятая это вообще синоним простого join :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете просто добавить подзапросом это поле:

```
SELECT s.*, 
    u.photo as photo, 
    u.city as city, 
    s.additional,
    ifnull((select distinct 1 from favourites f where f.sferaValue = s.sfera_value and f.user_id = u.user_id), 0) as is_favourite_flag
FROM sfera s join user u on u.user_id = s.user_id 
WHERE s.is_confirmed = '1' 
    AND s.sfera_value = 'Внутренние работы' 
    AND s.city_value = 'Москва'
    AND u.user_id = s.user_id 
ORDER BY rating DESC
```